# Load application with module load and specify a different name from the default

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, load

I am using my local workstation to run applications stored on our local cluster. To load and run an application, I normally use:

```
module load xxx
```

However, there is a an application on my computer that already has the same name as a module I am trying to load. I am afraid there might be a conflict when I load such a module. Is there a way similar to Python (`import xxx as yyy`) to load a module and specify a different name to it. Something like:

```
module load xxx as yyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) is a very handy package for switching your environment from being setup for one group of tools, transforming the `$PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc. so that it's configured for an entirely different set of tools. I'm familiar with it from working in the CAD/CAM industry where we used a in house product that did essentially the same thing.

Back to your issue, you cannot load a different module using modules like that, you can however do a `switch`:

```
$ module switch module1 module2
```

#### Example

```
$ module load gcc/3.1.1
$ which gcc
/usr/local/gcc/3.1.1/linux/bin/gcc
```

Now we'll switch to a different version of the module

```
$ module switch gcc gcc/3.2.0
$ which gcc
/usr/local/gcc/3.2.0/linux/bin/gcc
```